# Connection error on MySQL Workbench 6.1

Tags: mysql, shell, terminal, osx-yosemite-beta

I just upgraded my comp to the beta Yosemite and now my MySQL is giving me a connection problem.

I used to be able to run this command in terminal and get results:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -e "SELECT * FROM table_name"
```

But now it returns this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I'm not sure how I even set this connection up in the first place so please any answers, pretend I'm not too savvy with this... Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found out what happened. When I upgraded to Yosemite, this file disappeared or something. Anyway I had to reinstall the files. Everything is here in this link under the MySQL section:

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

Answer (score 3):

First, verify that your MySQL server is running:

```
mysql.server start
```

If that was not the issue, try starting the MySQL server in safe-mode using [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788381/getting-cant-connect-through-socket-tmp-mysql-when-installing-mysql-on-m)

Comment: On my Mac running Yosemite, I needed to start MySQL using the full path: `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`